# Can I get the source code for Android's Google Maps app?

Tags: android, google-maps

I read somewhere that all default android applications where opensource.

If this is true, I am trying to find the Google Maps code. Can anyone tell me how I might find it?

Comment: Android itself is open source. Google Maps isn't. You won't find the source anywhere I'm sorry to say.

Comment: If you are searching for a specific construct, you can decompile the APK-File and get the Dalvik Bytecode. As this is not the same as Java-Code, you need knowledge of the bytecode to transform it back into Java-Code.

Comment: @sisko- U got Google Map Application Source Code , i also want this thing, can we download from the android 2.3.4 Source code?

Answer (score 35):

[Nope](https://source.android.com/source/faqs.html#how-can-i-get-access-to-the-google-apps-for-android-such-as-maps)

You might want to use [Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/?hl=en) in your application.

Comment: Thanks, but we have Android Open Source code so we cant get Google Maps Application source code from this open source ,As we get code of home screen launcher code from this.?

Comment: There are many launchers... Each OEM has it's own launcher. Some of them are open sourced the rest are closed. Search for Launcher2 on Google.

Comment: I am looking for Google Maps App Source code because i have to implement Pre-cache map area Functionality in my application using google map API. Can i achieve this goal using Google Map API?

Comment: Even if you manage to do this, it's illegal as per the TOS

Comment: Thanks but can i implement this cache management of google map tiles using google MAP API? i am very new in Android so i am asking here. thanks Again

Comment: No if you really want to do this, you have to reverse engineer the Google Maps apk. Again this is illegal, and nearly impossible. The Google Maps Api does not support this.

Comment: Are u Sure about this ,The Google Maps APi does not Support caching of maps tiles? So In New Updated Google Maps Application of Android how its works and implemented by Android? they use some coding or Personal libraries?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5812/discussion-between-sam-k-and-reno)

Answer (score 2):

Although Android itself is open-source Googles propritary apps are closed source for obvious security and intellectual property reasons.

These proprietary apps include the following:

- Maps
- Navigation
- YouTube
- GMail

If you want to utilize these apps in their provided state you can trigger them using intents.

Each application will require parameters in the intent uri or extra parameters, however examples of these are easy to find.

Answer (score -2):

If you work in Eclipse, use the download manager to download these plugins:

- http://adt-addons.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/source/com.android.ide.eclipse.source.update
- http://adt-addons.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/binedit/com.android.ide.eclipse.binedit.update

They give you access to Android source platform and many applications.

Comment: But not the google applications that @Merlin mentioned in the previous post

Answer (score -2):

check in github may be you find a solution there

https://github.com/googlemaps

and you should install these two packages first
Google Play Services
Google Repository
then try to add this fragment in your layout

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

and then you should add this method to initialise the map

```
private void createMapView(){
    try {
    if(null == googleMap){
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.mapView)).getMap();

        /**
         * If the map is still null after attempted initialisation,
         * show an error to the user
         */
        if(null == googleMap) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Error creating map",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
} catch (NullPointerException exception){
    Log.e("mapApp", exception.toString());
}
```

}

https://github.com/glennsayers/AndroidMapsTutorial